# Как преобразовать сырую строку (raw) с кириллицей в обычную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть сырая (*raw*) строка, которую нужно превратить в обычную. В ней есть кириллические символы.

На зарубежных форумах увидел подобный способ:

```
s = r'тест\nfoo'
s.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
```

Но на выходе я получаю что-то типа этого:

```
ÑÐµÑÑ
foo
```

Каким образом можно провести корректное преобразование кириллицы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял - вы хотите операцию, обратную операции экранирования.

Т.е. получить из строки `"тест\\nfoo"` --> `"тест\nfoo"`.

Можно попробовать воспользоваться [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
In [64]: from ast import literal_eval

In [65]: s = r'тест\nfoo\ttext after <TAB>'

In [66]: print(s)
тест\nfoo\ttext after <TAB>

In [67]: res = literal_eval(f'"{s}"')
# NOTE: ------------------->  ^   ^
In [68]: print(res)
тест
foo     text after <TAB>
```